# Calling new PostgreSQL command from Java Application issue

Tags: c, postgresql

I have defined a new command `my_command` in PostgreSQL. This command takes the path of `ANALYZE` and inside `analyze.c`, I have a function to do some operations if its `my_command`.This command takes the input arguments: table name, column name and an input string.

When I run this command from command line `psql`, it works as expected. But when I call the same command from a java application, all the variables that store the input arguments are NULL.

I printed the value of the input string in gram.y file where I have defined `my_command`.
    `fprintf (stderr, "I am inside gram.y %s\n",n->inp_str);`
and the input string is printed correctly.

But when I print `stmt->inp_str` in the function `standard_ProcessUtility()` of `utility.c` for the case `T_VacuumStmt`, I get the value as NULL. This is as far as I could trace back from `analyze.c`.

I am not sure how running the command from an application can make a difference.

gram.y content gist:

---

```
MyStmt:
        my_keyword qualified_name name_list my_inp_str
            {
                VacuumStmt *n = makeNode(VacuumStmt);
                n->options = VACOPT_ANALYZE;
                n->freeze_min_age = -1;
                n->freeze_table_age = -1;
                n->relation = $2;
                n->va_cols = $3;
                n->inp_str = $4;
                fprintf (stderr, "I am inside gram.y %s\n",n->inp_str);

                $$ = (Node *)n;
            }
;
```

`char *inp_str` is added to the `struct VacuumStmt` in `parsenodes.h`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had mailed this question to the pgsql-hackers mailing list and I got a response that I had to add code to copy `inp_str` to `_copyVacuumStmt()`.

Once this was done, the command worked from the Java application too. I have asked for the reason why it worked from command line even without adding the above code. I will update the details once I get the details.